# Any point in having anything after a lookahead group?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I cannot imagine how the `c` in `a(?=b)c` would ever work and yet I find nothing against this pattern when searching on the internet. If this expression doesn't match anything, then neither does `(a(?=b)){N}` , for N > 1, right?

Comment: yep, what's the matter? like your's `c(?<=b)a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - your pattern is impossible to match. So what? I can code this too:

```
if (i == 1 && i == 2)
```

it will compile just fine and never be true either.

Compilers are usually only concerned with syntax and grammar, not logical correctness. Regex is no exception.

However, to answer your hinted at question, "why have pattern after a lookahead", yes it does make sense when the look ahead has variable length, for example:

```
a(?=.*b)[a-c]+
```

the look ahead here asserts there is a "b" *somewhere* ahead.